# Matrix Total Rows Column Search Conditional

Tags: matrix, assets, conditionals

So I have this conditional that works properly for entries with matrix rows:

```
{if {tech_documents:total_rows search:doc_thumb="IS_EMPTY"} > 0}
    ...
{if:else}
    ...
{/if}
```

However, entries that have no rows for this matrix field throw a template error:

> #### Error
>
> You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your
> conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing },
> or a missing {/if}.
>
> **Parser State**: Invalid Condition: Not enough operands for operator ” >
> “.

Running: EE 2.9, Matrix 2.6, Assets 2.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EE simply removes any tags corresponding to custom fields that have no data. So by the time EE is ready to parse the outer `{if}` conditional, it will look like this:

```
{if  > 0}
```

Try wrapping the field tag in quotes:

```
{if '{tech_documents:total_rows search:doc_thumb="IS_EMPTY"}' > 0}
```

Comment: I tried that too. Throws a similar error, except the parser statement reads: `Unexpected ‘IS_EMPTY’ (VARIABLE); expected RD in Template “hmc_site/tech-info” on line 79` which is the first line of the conditional statement

Comment: Did you try reversing the single/double quotes?

Comment: That worked! That's a first for me. Thanks for the help Brandon.

Comment: @Siebird Sweet! Just updated the code sample above.

Comment: @BrandonKelly is that something that could be fixed with prep_conditionals(). See the quote by Pascal here: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/245003/#1065255

Comment: The code works with single/double quotes. One style just needs to wrap the outer tag and the other style needs to wrap the parameter. I'm guessing using only one style prematurely closes the tag for this use case

Comment: @BjørnBørresen I don’t think so; The problem here is that Matrix code never gets called in the first place if the field is empty, so no amount of additional Matrix code is going to help :)

Answer (score 0):

try with below code:

```
{if tech_documents:total_rows > 0 && search:doc_thumb="IS_EMPTY"}
    ...
{if:else}
    ...
{/if}
```